# Suggested edit disappeared completely

Tags: support, stack-overflow, suggested-edits, review

I just started to review a question: [Configuring snmp on ESXi server using VI Java api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525224/configuring-snmp-on-esxi-server-using-vi-java-api) from the first reviewes queue.

The question contained urgency requests, and some grammar and formatting issues, so I started to fix them. After clicking the <kbd>Save Edits</kbd>-button, the text box was displayed that this suggestion has to be reviewed etc... So far everything work's as expected.
I then started to write a comment to the question, but discarded that.

After that my edit suggestion was gone (not rejected), and I couldn't click the <kbd>I'm Done</kbd> button either.

Could anyone enlighten me on what happened here?